# WPF Map Control with WMS Support

Tags: wpf, dictionary, gis, wms

Is anybody aware of a map control for WPF with WMS support that is considered stable? I've been looking around and coming up short on any recent efforts to build a map control for WPF.

I found the [Virtual Earth WPF Control](http://vewpf.codeplex.com/). It works fine, but it has a dependency on Bing Maps (as far as I can tell) and the project I'm working on will have a self-hosted WMS server. [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) is of interest, but lacks WPF support. [WPF SharpMap Controls](http://wpfsharpmapcontrols.codeplex.com/) adds WPF support to SharpMap, but is considered very unstable by its authors due to upcoming changes in SharpMap. I need something more stable today, if possible.

Is anybody aware of a stable WPF map control with WMS support?

Answer (score 0):

[SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) has good support for WMS.